# Script file can't create a java Jar file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, compiler-errors

I have the following script in a bat file.

```
path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin

prompt $$

cls

javac GUI.java

echo Main-Class: GUI>manifest.mf

jar cmf manifest.mf GUI.jar GUI.class

java -jar GUI.jar

pause
```

The Java file is compiled and the manifest file is created. However, when it comes to creating the Jar file, the command prompt gets stuck (hangs). It behaves as if it were on a loop.

! [Command Prompt Output]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO7gc.jpg

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to create the jar file? Can't you just do `java GUI` after `javac GUI.java`?

Comment: Yes. I did that and it works. However, this is a requirement for my class.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) (under jar command options > m) you should switch the manifest and jar file name, so `jar cmf GUI.jar manifest.mf GUI.class`

Comment: Tried it and nothing. It's strange. Maybe it's my computer. My teacher did it in his the exact same script and executed with no problem.

Comment: Yeah, it worked fine for me too. Are you sure your path is correct?

Comment: Yes. I also just updated JDK to the latest, updated the script, and added the Environment Variable path under 'User Variables' in the System Properties. With all of that, the problem persists.

Comment: One last question, are you sure you aren't using any libraries? Because a GUI often uses swing.

Comment: Yes. It is! It was a Java file provided by the teacher. It imports 3 libraries:import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

Comment: That complicates everything a ton. You should do the javac with the library (I believe it is called tomcat) and you need to find a way to make the jar file...

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks a million for your help! I'll post the outcome when I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The script was named 'jar' which caused problems. I renamed the file and it worked.